# Accessing global variables in Firefox extensions

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'm writing a Firefox extension which takes a custom switch from the command line and sets a variable inside my `cmdline.js` in the `components` directory, we'll call the variable `switchDetected` which is a boolean. Now based upon this variable I want actions to be carried out in my `overlay.js` file in the `chrome/content` directory.
The problem I'm having is I can't seem to be able to access the variable `switchDetected` that is declared in `components/cmdline.js` from within `chrome/contents/overlay.js`.

I've tried numerous ways of doing this but nothing seems to work. So I'm just wondering if anyone knows how this can be achieved.

Comment: SOLUTION (I'll add this properly when it lets me, 6 hours)

Typically I discovered the solution 10 minutes after posting the question. the solution is to use Javascript code modules. Here is the link

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/Using

I used getters and setters rather than exposing the variable I wanted to change as it seemed that exposing the variable itself didn't work, but functions did, which is good. 

I hope this saves others from endless searching.

Comment: Well, using JavaScript modules is another possibility - but if you have the XPCOM component already, you can just communicate with it directly. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A script loaded in an overlay runs in the context of the browser window - its global variables are stored as properties of the `window` object corresponding with the browser. If you open a second browser window the same script will load a second time and run in the context of the new browser window - it will have different global variables. The scripts containing XPCOM components on the other hand only load once and they have their independent context that isn't bound to a window. So their global variables cannot be accessed from a browser window directly, just like two browser windows cannot access each others global variables directly.

Instead the browser window should communicate with the XPCOM component using the usual approach: get a component instance and call its method. If you don't want to define your own interface for that (you probably don't) you can [use a trick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/wrappedJSObject), something like this:

```js
CommandLineHandler.prototype = {
  handle: function(commandLine) {...},
  get helpInfo() {...},
  isSwitchDetected: function()
  {
    return switchDetected;
  },
  get wrappedJSObject()
  {
    return this;
  },
  QueryInterface: XPCOMUtils.generateQI(["nsICommandLineHandler"]);
};
```

The `wrappedJSObject` property makes sure that your component can be unwrapped - all its methods and properties will become accessible then and not just the ones defined in the interface. So your overlay script needs to do the following:

```js
var cmdLineHandler = Components.classes["@myself.com/my-command-line-handler;1"]
                               .getService()
                               .wrappedJSObject;
var switchDetected = cmdLineHandler.isSwitchDetected();
```